# SQL - Problem with subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am currently learning SQL and I tried testing something but it does not work.

The query that I tried is the following:

```
SELECT acc_id 
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM company 
);
```

The inner query must return the whole table and the outter query must select from that table only a specific column. Simple as it seems this produces an error. The error message is:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6" (line 6 being the last line).

I can't figure out whats the issue.

Comment: I dont get it? Why cant you do a simple select `acc_id` from `Company`?

Comment: Why don't you select the acc_id from the company table directly?

Comment: You are using a *derived table* - but for no reason (that I can see)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give an alias to your subquery:

```
SELECT acc_id 
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM company 
) AS some_alias;
```

Although your query can be simplified into:

```
SELECT acc_id
FROM company;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I know this is a dummy question but the actual problem I am trying to solve invloves a more complicated query. The problem is still the same but this query was easier to explain.  Again thanks.